# UITableView - insert and deletion of rows at index path issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView that have three sections. `Section 0` have a fixed set of cells, `Section 1` can have a varying number of cells and `Section 2` is also fixed. When the user presses the last cell in `Section 2` then I want to add a row into `Section 1`.

My problem is when I tap the first row in `Section 2`, it seems to insert the row correctly. But when I later deletes a row I no longer can insert items (did didSelectRowAtIndexPath) down''t get called when I the the first row in `Section 2`. I guess it might be a problem with my reuseIdentifiers, but I can't see where. Any ideas?

My tabelView delegate methods looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [self reuseIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath];

    id cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell ) {

        cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    }

    // Update cell content..
    [self updateContentOfCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


//Helper method to return a reuseIdentifier for TBV cells.
- (NSString *)reuseIdentifierForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *reuseIdentifier;
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            reuseIdentifier = @"StandardCell";
            break;
        case 1:
            reuseIdentifier = @"SectionCellInWhichIWantToAddMoreCells";
            break;
        case 2:

            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    reuseIdentifier = @"WantToAddCellsToSectionOneByPressingAtThisRow";
                    break;
                case1 :
                    reuseIdentifier = @"OtheerCellInSectionTwo";
                    break;

        }

        break;

        default:
            reuseIdentifier = @"StandardCell";
            break;
    }

    return reuseIdentifier;
}


// Configure cell with type
- (void)configureCell:()cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            [self configureFirstSectionCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self configureFirstSectionCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self configureSecondSectionCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}

// Update cell content after reload
- (void)updateContentOfCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // exactly the same structure as configureCell but calls different (updateSecondSectionCell) methods in it's switch cases.
}

- (void)configureFirstSectionCell:(id)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Sets initial values of each cell

}


// Where I want to add things...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        [self.view endEditing:YES];

        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:1] inSection:1];

        [tableView beginUpdates];

        [self.dataSource addObject:@""];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [tableView endUpdates];

}
```

}

And I delete like this:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

What happens now is quite strange. When I tap the first row in `Section 2`, it seems to insert the row correctly. But when I later deletes a row I no longer can insert items (did didSelectRowAtIndexPath) down''t get called when I the the first row in `Section 2`. I guess it might be a problem with my reuseIdentifiers, but I can't see where. Any ideas?

Comment: is your issue resolved

Comment: in which method you wrote  delete action

Comment: In commitEditingStyle.

Comment: initially does the section1 have any rows?

Comment: It do at least have one row.

Comment: i guess in did select row this may be an issue.. insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] check once .. delete the row and then try to add and see what is the value of newindexpath? is it 0 or nil..

Comment: what is the value in newindexpath?

Comment: This is what I get when I po newIndexPath: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000096> {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 0) {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.dataSource addObject:@""];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Delete action code

```
-(void)delete
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[self.dataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```